# Can I indicate a preferred time for meetings?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, meetings

Meetings kill my productivity. I try to schedule them all together to minimize the damage.

Is there a way in outlook/exchange to indicate to people, when they're trying to schedule a meeting with me, which times are "better?" I can mark a block of time as busy easily enough, but I don't see a way to mark time as anti-busy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These isn't an "anti-busy" option, but if you'll submit a feature request to Microsoft it, I'll cast a vote in support.

The best approach that I've come up with is to use three of the "Show As:" options to express my schedule and my desires.

#### `Busy` (or `Out of Office`)

Use this to mark the times that you are in meetings, are away from the office, or just really need to focus on a task. Don't be afraid to schedule meetings/appointments with yourself as a way to block off time to get things done. (But don't overdo it.)

#### `Tentative`

Use this to mark off times that you'd *rather not* be invited to a meeting. The use of `Tentative` indicates that you are open to the idea, but you'd prefer that the meeting organizer try for a different time. If it's the only time that the other attendees are mutually available, you're willing to accept that, but a considerate organizer will try their best to find another slot.

#### `Free` (or just leave the calendar empty)

Use this to indicate times that you are fully willing to attend a meeting -- what you refer to above as "better" times.

All of the above assumes that others in your organization will respect your use of the various "Show As" categories. But if they won't respect that, there isn't much you that technology can do to help you.